# How to register app-global actions in flutter using Shortcuts/Intent/Actions?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-shortcuts

Using the [Shortcuts](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Shortcuts-class.html) and [Actions](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Actions-class.html) widget it is easy to add actions which are invoked while the focus is below the actual `Actions` widget.

But in my use case I have a master/detail view layout where I want the master view handle shortcuts (like 'next item'/'previous item') even if the detail view is in focus. (and potentially the other way around, I want the detail view to handle shortcuts while the master view has focus).

The only workaround I found was to create an action on the root level on which the master and detail view can listen - but this feels like it circumvents the whole `Shortcuts`/`Intent`/`Action` framework.

So is there a way to have the `Actions` registered at the root of the app, instead of at the specific context location inside the focus tree?

---

To be a bit more specific:

[image: AuthPass screenshot with master/detail view]

the "master view" is the list of password entries, while the "detail view" gives the fields/information about the password. Even if the focus is on the list view the `CopyPasswordIntent` should be handled by the detail view, while even when the user has the focus in the detail view a `SearchIntent` should always revert the focus back to the list view's search field.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I have been looking for ways to solve this but flutter is really bad at the focusing system, I haven't found any reliable way to implement focus and shortcuts system properly

Comment: It seems like Flutter's shortcut/action system is really poorly designed. To me, shortcuts should be a top level thing, which receives input if not consumed by some IME (i.e., a text field) that then generates intents to invoke actions which register for those intents deeper down the tree. But instead, focus must be below the action? This seems backwards to me.